# Automate file transfer from Windows to Unix

Tags: shell-script, windows, ftp, file-copy

I have the following situation: users update `csv`/`txt` files on daily basis on Windows. I use those flat files as input for my Oracle scripts which is on Unix. I need a script/method of transferring those flat files from Windows to Unix.

Comment: What kind of access do you have on the Unix machine? Shell (SSH), FTP, anything else?

Comment: Don't use ftp, it makes username/password travel the network in clear text. Scp is easiest to script alternative, sftp isn't too bad either. Check Bruce's answer.

Comment: `WinSCP.exe` is a useful tool, as well as using `PuTTy.exe` (like @BruceEdiger mentioned)

Answer (score 8):

You could use the SCP program that comes with famed terminal emulator [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/): pscp.exe

If you create public/private key files, pscp.exe should have the ability to just do something like:

`pscp *.csv *.txt  username@unixhost:whatever/subdirectory/`

from inside a .bat file.

Comment: A cmd file would give him the extended syntax on windows. `psftp` is another option with putty.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options available. Choose one that you are most comfortable with. One potential would be to set up an SMB/CIFS share on the Unix host.

In a script from each Windows workstation, mount the SMB/CIFS share with the `net` command.

`net use \\computername\sharename /persistent:no`

After completion of the `copy` or `move` of the file to the SMB/CIFS share, you could optionally remove the share from the Windows workstation.

`net use \\computername\sharename /delete`

You can get full options of the `net` command by running `net help use`. Here is a good [unofficial guide](http://www.oregontechsupport.com/samba/samba.php) to configuring Samba.